# How to use d3.csv to load variable instead of file?

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm using D3.js to load csv file. It should look like this:

```
id,
a,
b,
```

But the csv is created inside my code, so I store it in a variable like this:

```
var flare = 'id,\na,\nb,\n'
```

However, the script does not work:

```
d3.csv(flare, function(error, data){
  if(error) throw error;
});
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Is the generated csv variable in the same page with the d3.csv function?

Comment: just dont use d3.csv and use flare as the data

Comment: @echonax Yes, it is got through a http request in the same javascript file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the version of D3 you are going to use, you have to choose the appropriate function:

#### v3.x

In versions 3.x [`d3.csv.parse()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) is what you are looking for:

> Parses the specified string, which is the contents of a CSV file, returning an array of objects representing the parsed rows.

For your example this would be

```
var flare = 'id,\na,\nb,\n';
var data = d3.csv.parse(flare);
```

#### v4+

For version 4 and above the CSV parser has become part of the [d3-dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv) module.  The function is now named [`d3.csvParse()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#csvParse).

```
var flare = 'id,\na,\nb,\n';
var data = d3.csvParse(flare);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I can't use d3.csv.parse in the latest released version of d3 https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.44.min.js, in which it says "d3.csv.parse is not a function".

Comment: @SijiaXiao I have edited my answer to include the solution for D3 v4.