# D3: How do I parse a CSV string into an object where keys are column names and values are arrays of data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I want to use D3 v3.5.6 to convert a CSV string into a Javascript object where column names are keys and their data are in arrays.

My JS so far:

```
var csvString= 'date,dow,sp500,nasdaq\n1/1/16,10,15,8\n1/3/16,5,3,7\n1/5/16,12,18,12\n';
var headers = []
d3.csv.parse(csvString, function(data){
  headers = d3.keys(data);
});
```

This fills array `headers` with strings of column names, but I cannot figure out how to get the data.

I would like to make an object like this:

```
{
  "date": ["1/1/16","1/3/16","1/5/16"],
  "dow": ["10","5","12"],
  ...
}
```

Is this possible with just D3?

Here is the CSV string in easy-to-read form:

```
date,dow,sp500,nasdaq
1/1/16,10,15,8
1/3/16,5,3,7
1/5/16,12,18,12
```

Comment: Do you need D3 to do it, or can you just create the array of values in javascript and then feed it to D3?

Comment: @TimConsolazio  I prefer D3 since it easily identifies column names with `d3.keys()` method. But if there are other ways to end up with the result I want, I am open to those.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37323768/4235784 .

Comment: @altocumulus That comes close, but not exactly in the format I want. That solution parses CSV string into `[{"date":"1/1/16"},{"date":"1/3/16"}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apart from `d3.csv.parse()`, it seems to me that this problem has little to do with D3, and can be solved with pure JavaScript:

```js
var csvString = 'date,dow,sp500,nasdaq\n1/1/16,10,15,8\n1/3/16,5,3,7\n1/5/16,12,18,12\n';

var data = d3.csv.parse(csvString);

var headers = d3.keys(data[0]);

var myObject = {};

headers.forEach(function(d) {
    myObject[d] = [];
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
    for (var key in d) {
        myObject[key].push(d[key]);
    }

});

console.log(myObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This routine parses an array of those strings (assuming the format is consistent) and returns them as an array of strings formatted the way you want. If you want the object and not the strings, modify the function (I put a comment). You should be able to just feed this to D3.

```
   var d3Data = splitStockStrings ( [
                    'date,dow,sp500,nasdaq\n1/1/16,10,15,8\n1/3/16,5,3,7\n1/5/16,12,18,12\n',
                    'date,dow,sp500,nasdaq\n1/1/17,10,15,8\n1/3/17,5,3,7\n1/5/17,12,18,12\n'
                ] );
  console.log ( d3Data );

  function splitStockStrings ( stockStrings ) {
    var newStrings = [];

    stockStrings.forEach ( function ( d ) {             
      var final = [];
      d.split ( '\n' ).forEach ( function ( frag, i ) {
        if ( i > 0 && frag.split ( ',' ) [ 0 ] ) {
          final.push ( frag.split ( ',' ) [ 0 ] );
        }
      });

      var obj = { date : final };
      var json = JSON.stringify ( obj );
      newStrings.push ( json );
      // Or if you don't want strings,
      // comment out the above and uncomment the below...
      // newStrings.push ( obj );
    });

    return newStrings;
   }
```

Comment: In my case, the input format would not match the strings in `d3Data`. My strings would have the same format as outlined in my code. All the data would be in one string.

Comment: Right I know it's not the end result: but this should give you the idea. You just need to look at the split and pick out the right vals to extend what I've done here.

Answer (score -1):

Using underscore (only cause that is what Im used to, you could use regular js map/forEach)

```
var csvArray = csvDataString.split(',');
var keys = _.first(csvArray);
var values = _.rest(csvArray);
var asArrayOfObjects = _.map(values, function(row) {
  var mapping = {};
  _.each(row, function(rowItem, i) { mapping[keys[i]] = rowItem }, {});  
  return mapping;
});
```

Comment: Why the `const` identifiers? In your example, what does `csv` represent?

Comment: replace const with var if you prefer, its just ES6. CSV is your string containing the CSV data. Ill update the naming